# Get Url with Cheerio and Node Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

I want to scrape link from this website

Web: https://generator.email/xixaiu1z@warnerwave.xyz

```
<a class="button-link" href="HTTPS:://IMTHELINK.COM" style="color: #FFFFFF; text-decoration: none; display: inline-block" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">
```

Confirm

I just need HTTPS:://IMTHELINK.COM

How to get that with cheerio?

I try with this code but the result is always undefined. I don't understand what happenned

```
const $ = cheerio.load(text);
const src = $(".button-link").text();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`text()` gets the text from text node descendants of an element.

It doesn't get attribute values. Use `attr('attribute-name')` for that.